Couldnot add appsettings with colon via Bicep script to Azure App service
I'm trying to set up variables in the appsettings.json file for my Azure App Service. These variables use the colon (:) notation for nested configuration.
When I manually add these settings through the Azure portal, everything works fine:

However, when I attempt to add the same configuration using a Bicep script, it fails.
Here is the Bicep script I’m using to set the app settings:
var dbConnectionString = 'test connection'

resource siteconfigWebjob 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: windowsAppService
  name: 'appsettings'
  properties: {
    'ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection': dbConnectionString
  }
}

Additionally, I tried adding the app settings directly in the App Service configuration within the Bicep file:
resource windowsAppService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: webjobAppServiceName
  location: resourceGroupLocation
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: windowsappServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: storageConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'MaxCsvFileSizeInBytes'
          value: '4194304'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


How does it fail?  Is there an error message?  If so, can you revise your post to include it?

I tried this method and it worked for me.
var defaultConnection = 'DefaultConnection'
var tenantConnection = 'TenantConnection'
var applicationInsightConnectionString = 'ApplicationInsightsConnectionString'
var emailProcessorEndpoint = 'EmailProcessorEndpoint'


resource siteconfigWebjob 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: windowsAppService
  name: 'appsettings'
  properties: {
    'ConnectionStrings:${defaultConnection}': dbConnectionString
    'ConnectionStrings:${tenantConnection}': tenantDbConnection
    'ConnectionStrings:${applicationInsightConnectionString}': applicationInsights.properties.ConnectionString
    AzureWebJobsDashboard: storageConnectionString
    AzureWebJobsStorage: storageConnectionString
    MaxCsvFileSizeInBytes: '4194304'
    WebsiteUrl: 'https://${frontendAppServiceName}.azurewebsites.net'
    'EventGridCredentials:${emailProcessorEndpoint}': emailProcessor.properties.endpoint
    
  }
}


When trying to add the app setting using portal also, it is not working for me with colon mark.

Basically, the conventional way of naming an app setting name should include only letters, numbers, underscores, periods as highlighted below.
I have used below notation to name an app setting and also added nested app settings as shown below.
'ConnectionStrings_DefaultConnection': dbConnectionString
You can either add an app setting under siteconfig block with Microsoft.Web/sites resource provider or add a separate resource provider called Microsoft.Web/sites/config as detailed below.
param webApp string = 'xxx'
param sku string = 'S1'
param linuxFxVersion string = 'php|7.4'
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var webAppName = '${webApp}-webapp'
var appServicePlan = 'AppServicePlan-${webApp}'


resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: appServicePlan
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  kind: 'linux'
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}
resource webAppPortal 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: webAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appService.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'xxxx'
        }
        {
          name: 'MaxCsvFileSizeInBytes'
          value: '4194304'
        }
        {
          name: 'ConnectionStrings_DefaultConnection'
          value: dbConnectionString
        }
    ]
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
      ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
    }
    httpsOnly: true
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

var dbConnectionString = 'test connection'
resource siteconfigWebjob 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: webAppPortal
  name: 'appsettings'
  properties: {
    'ConnectionStrings_DefaultConnection': dbConnectionString
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:



